# Equality of Two functions

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $f,g : B \to C$ be any two functions. Suppose that $f \circ h = g \circ h$ for every function $h: A \to B$. Prove that $f = g$.

This is a problem form Pinter's Set Theory. I am trying to solve it but got no clue. Somebody help me please.

Comment: Hint: what does composition with the identity function do?

Comment: You mean h can be selected as an identity function on B. This is what Mr Arten Marvin suggested in his comment.

Comment: The assumption that $A$ has an element is necessary since if $A=\emptyset$ then you can construct counterexamples.

Comment: @Mohsen Isn't this obvious because A = Dom(h)?

Comment: @Mr.MBB No. There is a (single) function with empty domain: the empty function. If $h$ is the empty function, then so are $f\circ h$ and $g\circ h$ and so the compositions are equal, even if $f$ and $g$ are distinct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ can be chosen how ever you want, then (as in a comment/answer suggested) take $A=B$ and $h(x)=x$. If, however, $A$ is any nonempty given set, then fix $x_0\in B$ and define $h(x):=x_0$ to be a constant function. Then since $f\circ h=g\circ h$ we have that $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$. Repeating this argument for every $x_0\in B$ gives $f=g$ as desired.

Comment: I like this better.

Comment: Thx. You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** Let $A = B$ and let $h(x) = x$.

Comment: I was thinking about it. Do you think the hypotheses means A can be any set? In that case we can select h = I_b identity function on B.

Comment: @Mr.MBB Without any other context I would assume yes.